# Common jazz chord progressions

Tags: chords

I am familiar with circle progression (ascending 4th descending 5th) and secondary dominants but i was curious about other more advanced progressions.

Comment: Like tts, or what?

Comment: Google "The Rhythm changes" and the blues for starters.

Comment: @Duston, but rhythm changes is just part of the circle perhaps with some mods.  If the OP knows circle they know just about everything.

Comment: It is hard to answer this question as worded.  "other more advanced progressions" will mean different things to different people.  Some would say that the circle progression is about as advanced as you get.  Can you provide an example song that uses the circle as its primary set of changes?

Answer (score 3):

Jazz can, and does, do all sorts of things.   But ii, V, I, with or without colorful extensions and b5 substitutions keeps popping up!   It isn't always ii, V, I into the SAME tonic though.  It's such a strong mini-progression that you can pick your destination almost arbitrarily. Look up Coltrane's 'Giant Steps' which is basically a series of ii, V, I progressions into tonics a third apart.

Answer (score 2):

ii-V-I is just the last 3 chords of the circle progression.  Jazz is filled with strings of ii-V's because they use cycle extensions to create modulation and resolution to each "important" chord change.  The fact is that any song can go any where and there are tons of Jazz tunes that jump all around.  A common example is descending Major key changes.  G --> F --> Eb --> etc.  The ii-V's are tossed in to create smooth movement.  In terms of what seems "common" in the Real book I would mention 2 sets of changes worth memorizing.  The first is Rhythm Changes and the second is the 12 bar Blues.  Rhythm changes has two fundamental sets of changes and is structured in the form A-A-B-A.  This is a reference to the overall architecture of the tune, not the chords.  The A section is usually,

||: I --> VI7 --> ii-7 --> V7 :||

v-7 --> I7 --> IV --> iv-7

I --> VI7 --> ii-7 --> V7

The B section is the circle of 4th

III7 --> VI7 --> II7 --> V7

each chord played for 2 measures.

The first line is similar to Heart and Soul (a old 30s standard made popular as a 50s Rock ballad).

||: I --> vi --> VI --> V :||

There are slight variations on the same theme.  A lot of Jazz tunes use the dom 7 on the vi chord, leading into the ii, but not all do.  Examples of songs are too numerous to cite but a few over done ones are Oleo, Anthropology, Dexterity.  And one more is Eric's Schmooze Blues by Joe Pass.

Next if the 12 bar blues.  A stripped down version might be.

I -> IV -> I -> I

IV -> IV -> I ->I

V -> IV -> I ->I

there are 100s of variants, especially in the last line where the "turn around" is placed to create a resolution to the I at the top.  A few examples, All Blues, Blue Monk, C Jam Blues, West Coast Blues, Good Bye Pork Pie Hat.

There are a couple other noteworthy ones, How High the Moon has descending whole step key changes and is used in Ornithology and several other standards but in reality one can find endless variation.  Now here is where things change course.  It not not be necessary or even wise to get all these progressions worked out.  Instead learn song structures like AABA, ABA, ABAC, etc and learn the art of modulation, chord substitution and polychords.  Not only is there a ii-V-I (which is an inverted IV-V-I imo) but there is a iv-ii-V-I (Rhythm changes), and a iii-iv-ii-V-I, etc.  All the way out to the circle,

I - IV - vii - iii - vi - ii - V - I

This is actually just the following (I IV V) in disguise.

I - IV - V - I - I - IV - V - I

A great book on modulation is Modulation by Max Reger.  In there he walks through every possible key change and how to connect them with some type of cycle extension.  These inevitably can be broken into strings of ii-V's hence the emphasis on ii-V's in many Jazz improv work books.  The changes in the Real Book are not necessarily even the original ones but they are still good.  You can start by running through them at random and place them in a category based in similarity of the changes and architecture.  You will then see how prevalent the three types of changes I mentioned are.  And you will see how often the ii-V is used to cycle through and modulate from one key to another.  You definitely will find exceptions, Giant Steps being one.  Though it is full of classic ii-V's the modulations are unique, which I think is what Coltrane was going for.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very nice piece by Bill Evans called "Comrade Conrad", which is a weird piece that goes through all the keys. Basically, it is an ordinary Jazz standard, except that after each chorus (as they call it I'm told) it has modulated a 5th upward. Therein you can find all sorts of Jazz cadenzas, and it's a fun way of practicing improvisation in various keys.